# SSIS default value is not being set when source value in null

Tags: ssis

Problem:
OLEDB source has null value in phone.
Destination table has Phone NOT NULL DEFAULT 1234567.
OLEDB destination has Keep Nulls unchecked

According to what I read here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187887(v=sql.110).aspx

The default value for the column should be inserted if incoming value is NULL.

But it's not happening. And I don't want to do any transformation in SSIS. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the answer is that for Keep Nulls option to work the column has to be missing from the data source.

create table #tmpdel
(
a INT NOT NULL default 0,
b INT NOT NULL default 0
)

Insert into #tmpdel(a) values(1) - WORKS
Insert into #tmpdel(a, b) values(1, null) - FAILS

Answer (score 1):

In your Data Flow Task, in OLE_DB source, set the data access mode to 'SQL command' and write out a select statement as below

```
SELECT Column_A
    ,Column_B
    ,ISNULL(Phone, 1234567)
    ,Column_C
    ,Column_D etc.
FROM Source_Table
```

Comment: I know I can do that but I still want to know why this is not happening " For example, if there is a null field in a data file, the default value for the column is loaded instead." according to the document above

Comment: Another source says the same thing...           Keep Nulls - Again by default this setting is unchecked which means default value will be inserted (if the default constraint is defined on the target column) during insert into the destination table if NULL value is coming from the source for that particular column. If you check this option then default constraint on the destination table's column will be ignored and preserved NULL of the source column will be inserted into the destination. Reference https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1840/sql-server-integration-services-ssis-best-practices/

Answer (score 0):

you can write CASE statement in SQL command in Data Flow Task:

```
select 
CASE
 when PhoneNumber IS NUll   then '1234567' else  table_name.PhoneNumber END as PhoneNumber,

from table table_name
```

Comment: I know I can do that but I still want to know why this is not happening " For example, if there is a null field in a data file, the default value for the column is loaded instead." according to the document above

Answer (score 0):

Here's a work-around that works for me. Most of my tables have two columns `CREATED_BY` and `DATE_CREATED` which default to `SUSER_SNAME()` and `GETDATE()` respectively.

I usually import data through a very simple view rather than directly into the target table itself. I use a simple view, e.g. `SELECT COL_A, COL_B FROM MY_TABLE`. (There are good reasons to import this way: If I need to update the target table at some point, I can tinker with it as much as I like, and only need to update the view when I'm ready to update the SSIS package.)

The view doesn't contain the `CREATED_BY` and `DATE_CREATED` columns. In my case, this works because I never expect to import data into these two columns. This won't work in other cases, where some data is expected, and the default is only used when there is no data for the column in some rows of the source file.

To the deeper and very important question that Sam asked as to *why* this these defaults don't work: I don't know. I believe it is a bug in SSIS. The fact that this post is from **8 years ago** (longer in other posts), that it's *still* a problem and there is *still* no answer on any MS site is a sign of the contempt that Microsoft has for SSIS users. There are so many bugs and examples of bad design that never get rectified in SSIS that it's hard to think of other explanations.